# Spring Cloud Gateway - Redirect Based on Header

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Just using Spring Cloud Gateway, I'm currently proxying a remote site with the following route (defined in Kotlin):

```
@GetMapping("/proxgoo/**")
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun proxyPath(proxy: ProxyExchange<*>): ResponseEntity<*> {
    val path = proxy.path("/proxgoo/")
    return proxy.uri(proxiedRemote.toString() + "/" + path).get()
}
```

Which works nicely. If we set the `proxiedRemote` to `https://www.google.com`, this works great untill we try to load the external resources (like the images).

The problem is that something like:

`http://localhost:8081/logos/doodles/2018/**`

Really should be going out to:

`http://localhost:8081/proxgoo/logos/doodles/2018/**`

I was thinking that if I could redirect everything, where the **Referer** header is `http://localhost:8081/proxgoo/` back onto the proxy route, then this would be all that I need:

---

So, the actual question. I thought that the following config would redirect everything with the request header **Referer**=`http://localhost:8081/proxgoo/`, but it doesn't pick it up. Have I done something silly?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: redirect_on_referer
        predicates:
        - Header=Referer,http://localhost:8081/proxgoo/
        filters:
        - RedirectTo=302, http://localhost:8081/proxgoo/
```

Answer (score 0):

This under `routes` should get you going there:

```
- id: redirect_on_referer
  uri: http://localhost:8081
  predicates:
    - Header=Referer, http://localhost:8081/proxgoo/
  filters:
    - RewritePath=/(?<segment>.*), /proxgoo/$\{segment}
```